# Reading a JSON file from a website with PHP and, or Javascript.

Tags: php, json

I usually read the source code of a site to get the information I have to work with. I do this with

```
$url="http://www.urlexample.com";     
file_get_contents($url);
```

Now I find a much more difficult task: On a website ("fibalivestats.com") there is a div which content I would like to read, but when using file_get_contents the div content is empty. The div at the html source code looks like this:

```
<div id ="aj_pbp"></div>
```

Yes, it is 'empty'. But the outer html is different (not empty). How do they fill the content of this div?

They use a js function like this:

```
function loadData()  {
 var language = jQuery("html").attr("lang") || '';
 var datapath = jQuery("#datapath").val() || '';
 var jsonfile = datapath + 'data.json';
 jQuery.getJSON(jsonfile,function(data)  {
 jQuery.each(data, function(key,val)  {
  if(key == 'pbp')  {
    var pbp = '';
    var minipbp = '';
    var currentperiod = 0;
    jQuery.each(val, function(index,p)  {
      var pernum = p['period'];
      var ptype = 'reg';

...

}
```

I can't even reach to the complete path of the .json file, as there's something like #datapath that I can't find.

The function is much larger. As you see, they get the info from a json file, called 'data.json'.

The question is: how could I get to the info contained in that json file with PHP and JS? How could I find the complete path of the .json file?

Comment: Testing your hacking skills?

Comment: They fill it using JavaScript. The browser which loaded that HTML and their JavaScript simply executes the JS and populates HTML with more HTML.

Comment: @Theofanis No. I simply want to be able to store and work with public information. I want to store exactly what is available when you visit the site, not any other hidden information.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no.  With php's file_get_contents you cant get any of the html that is loaded after the server has served up html. Javascript is run in the clients browser.
file_get_contents() is not a browser and therefore will not run any JS, it only gets the html that the server serves up.

There would potentially be hacky ways of doing it with javascript webscraping on node.js. but you have asked for a php solution so that is outside the scope of your question.

further reading about JS solutions can be found here:

> https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js